# pagination of thumbnails with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I have to code below in a sidebar.

- @apartment.assets.each do |asset|
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"}
            = image_tag(asset.image.url(:thumb))

This generates all the (thumb) images of an apartment with click to the original image.  My idea this to show max 10 and with some nice pagination gem kaminari.

I could not find any code/howto examples of has_many relationships with kaminari. Someone ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@apartment.assets.page(params[:page]).tap do |assets|
   assets.each do |asset| %li %a{:href => "#"} = image_tag(asset.image.url(:thumb))
   = paginate(:assets)
end
```

Don't know much about kaminari and don't know much about Haml, but it *could* work :-)